# How to abort evaluation when clicking CancelButton in program with Dialog boxes?

Tags: programming, conditional, dialog-window

If you run the following code you will notice when Cancelbutton is clicked, the output is an $Abort, but it continues running the following cells, I tried different things but no one works.
I want to abort evolution if CancelButton is clicked, but the code keeps open the next Dialog boxes and execute them.
I tried to use FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"] but it doesn't help. I tried also with an If for CancelButton but it runs the same.

Can you help me with this?

```
men = ChoiceDialog["Click OK to import data base"];
If[men == True,
 base = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
 datoscsv = Import[base];, 
 DialogInput["Program has been canceled"] && Abort[]]

(*This part I tried with  DialogInput[{TextCell["Program has been canceled"], 
  DefaultButton[DialogReturn[OK="True"]] 
If [OK==True,Abort[]]*)

(*Next Dialog box*)

DialogInput[{TextCell[
    "Insert Lesson number"], 
   InputField[Dynamic[ln], Number], 
   DefaultButton[DialogReturn[lec = ln + 1]], CancelButton[]}];
lec;
renglon = datoscsv[[lec ;; lec , All]];
contenido = Flatten[renglon];
```